# Three table side by side overflow of div container?

Tags: css, layout, html

I've got a problem with my page's layout.
I want to create 3 table and set them side by side, so I set float attribute of them is "left", but the height of div container only fix with the 3rd table, two first table is overflow of the div. Please help me to fix it.
Here is my page

```
<body>

<div id="main">

    <table id="tbSA" class="tb">
        <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tbShops" class="tb">
        <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
    </table>

</div>
</body>​
```

and here is style

```
body {
    background-color: #5c87b2;
}
#main {
    margin: 10px 10px 15px 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

table, td {
  border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
}

.tb {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort problem is because your first two table are floated. but the last one is not so the div will correctly resize to it to wrap the **third table**.

But it order to make the div wrap around the floated table too. You have to clear the floats.

There are many ways to solve this:

1. The safest way is to use, a clearing div just before closing the parent div <sup>[[Demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/gUFBh/)</sup>

   ```
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
   ```
2. Old popular way is to give `overflow:hidden` which will force the div to wrap around all the elements. *This is what other answers are focused out* [[Demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/gUFBh/1/)
3. The third way is to use a `.clearfix` class and is the most popular way nowadays. [[Demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/gUFBh/2/)

   ```
   .clearfix:after {
       content: ".";
       display: block;
       clear: both;
       visibility: hidden;
       line-height: 0;
       height: 0;
   }

   html[xmlns] .clearfix {
       display: block;
   }

   * html .clearfix {
       height: 1%;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways, i would prefer using `overflow:hidden;` for `#main`.

http://jsfiddle.net/QBj6R/

```
#main {
    margin: 10px 10px 15px 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/295264) answer to see why overflow hidden is not always the best method

Answer (score 1):

Your table have `float` on it so you have to **clear** his parent which is `#main`.

```
#main{
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/VbvLq/1/

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/295264) answer to see why overflow hidden is not always the best method

Comment: @Starx It's never be a bad method Because it's work till IE6. But .clearfix have there limitation it's work till IE8

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i understand the question correctly but if you want to put the tables side by side, why dont you just wrap them in another table? Example:

```
<div id="main">
    <table>
        <tr style="width:33%;">
            <td >
                <table id="tbSA" class="tb">
                    <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width:33%;">
                <table id="tbShops" class="tb">
                    <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td style="width:33%;">
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Code</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Set the width of each td in the wrapping table to 33% and it will set all the tables next to each other